# minimal example of an installable python module

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

Say I have a directory with some .py files, and some directories with other .py files

That directory is called my_program

```
my-program
 -- dir1
    -- file.py
 -- dir2
```

I want to be able to use my_program's defined modules **from any directory**, say by doing

```
>>> import my_program
>>> myprogram.dir1.file.function()
```

or by doing

```
>>> import my_program.dir1.file
>>> file.function()
```

I also want to "install" my module for systemwide acessibility using pip

Answer (score 3):

A minimal working example follows

```
my_packs/
├── foo
│   ├── code.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── setup.py
```

here code.py constains some useful function, and setup.py contains

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(name="foo",
      version="0.1",
      description="A foo utility",
      author="Ewen Cheslack-Postava",
      author_email='me@ewencp.org',
      platforms=["any"],  # or more specific, e.g. "win32", "cygwin", "osx"
      license="BSD",
      url="http://github.com/ewencp/foo",
      packages=find_packages(),
      )
```

and init is an empty file

the package can be installed with

```
python setup.py develop
```

or

```
pip install -e .
```

and then, from any dir, it runs like follows:

```
python -c 'import foo.code; print(foo.code.useful_function())'
```

Example adapted from: https://ewencp.org/blog/a-brief-introduction-to-packaging-python/index.html

Comment: is setup tools still the "current" way to do things?